# AVR MCUs parametric search shows number of USB modules but no USB interface

Tags: microcontroller, usb, avr

I am looking for AVR MCUs that have USB 2.0 (or greater) capabilities. Using their [website for Parametric search](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/parametric-search.html), I see that some MCUs have USB modules, but they are not listed as MCUs that have a USB interface:

[image: microchip parametric search]

Looking at the Datasheet of [AT90USBXXX](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc7593.pdf) (which the website says it has USB module but not USB interface), I see that it has USB capabilities:

[image: AT90XXX datasheet]

1. So, what is the difference between "USB Interface" and "USB module"?
2. Did Microchip (Or previously Atmel) just forgot to include the "USB interface feature" for these MCUs which have USB modules?

Comment: Silicon vendors can make super-advanced microcontrollers with extreme amounts of memory and peripherals on a itty bitty tiny QFN package. But building a web site with a useful parametric search in order to sell their products is a task completely beyond them - it's been mission impossible for 100% of all silicon vendors for as long as the internet has existed... Open a support ticket with Microchip and ask them how exactly their web site makes sense.

Comment: Another fine example of the difference between engineers and marketroids.